# How can I calculate alpha and beta in this specific case?

Tags: geometry

[image]

It seems impossible to calculate $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Point $A$ divides $c$ line in half, $a+b=80=d$, $h=20$, $c=50$

I tried to work from the right triangle to the left one like this:

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{x}{a}$$
$$\tan\beta=\frac{c}{2(h+x)}$$
I really don't want to put $\cos\alpha$ in the $\tan\beta$ equation, simply because I'm looking for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and If I put them together, What do I do? Nothing.

I'm missing something with $a+b=d$. Any tips?

Show your approach to this problem.

Comment: Do you know that the two segments at $A$ are perpendicular?  That gives $\alpha + \beta = \frac \pi 2$  How do you get the numerator in the $\tan \beta$ equation to be $c$?  It should be the segment left of $A$.  MathJax hint:  you can put backslashes before common functions to get the right font and spacing, so \cos \alpha gives $\cos \alpha$

Comment: Use $\sin\alpha=\frac c{2a}$ and $\sin\beta=\frac c{2b}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by writing Pythagoras' theorem in the triangle on the right.
$$a^2=\left(\frac c2\right)^2+x^2$$
$$x^2=a^2-625$$
$$x=\sqrt{a^2-625}$$
Then use this $x$ for the triangle on the left:
$$(h+x)^2+\left(\frac c2\right)^2=b^2$$
$$h^2+x^2+2hx+\left(\frac c2\right)^2=b^2$$
$$400+a^2-625+40\sqrt{a^2-625}+625=(80-a)^2$$
$$400+40\sqrt{a^2-625}=6400-160a$$
$$\sqrt{a^2-625}=15-4a$$
You can square it, find $a$, then $b$, and then $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If you want, you can get $x$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Note $a = \frac{c}{2\sin\alpha}$ and $b = \frac{c}{2\sin\beta}$. Plug them into $a+b=80$ and $b\cos\beta - a\cos\alpha = h$ to get the system of equations for the angles

$$\cot\beta=\frac45+\cot\alpha, \>\>\>\>\>\csc\beta=\frac{16}5-\csc\alpha$$

Eliminate $\beta$ to get $4\csc\alpha + \cot\alpha=6$, or

$$3\tan^2\frac{\alpha}2 -12\tan\frac{\alpha}2+5=0$$
Thus, the angles are $\alpha = 2\tan^{-1}\frac{6-\sqrt{21}}3$ and $\beta= 2\tan^{-1}\frac{6-\sqrt{21}}5$.